# UV mapping loses edges & vertices

Tags: animation, uv, edges, uv-image-editor

I'm a complete beginner who wishes to speed-up the rendering duration of my animation by UV mapping my background objects (that do not participate in the animation) into a 2D texture. However, whenever I do this, I lose the edges of those objects.

**Approach**

I highlight the mesh objects within my scene collection that I wish to UV map.

I go into the "UV editor", -> "UV",->"Smart UV Project".

I go into "Shading", "use nodes", "add (image texture)", "bake", and connect the "color" from (image texture) to the "color" in the (emission node) and connect the "emission" to the "surface" of the (material output).

Thanks!

**Initial image** (only the black and white atoms move)

[image]

**After UV mapping the yellow spheres**

[image]